# Does Local API Hooks trigger Anti-Virus Flags?

Tags: windows, antivirus

If I do API hooking on my local Address Space (without doing dll injection on other process), will the AVs be triggered?

Comment: The answer for this is different for every AV and endpoint product, and likely changes over time as new heuristics are written and old heuristics are deprecated.